# Is it wrong to say "Welcome" to a supervisor?

Tags: exclamations, social-interaction

Today one of my supervisors incorporated stealthy and late into the shift and I saluted her with "Welcome!". My coworker implied that because she is the supervisor I should salute her with an informal "Hi!" instead. I know little about her role or what she does and definitely not my friend.

According to [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/welcome):

> welcome
> exclamation
>
> - said as a greeting to someone arriving at a place:
> - *Welcome - please come in*.
> - *Welcome **home/back** - we've missed you!*
> - *Welcome **to** Cambridge*.

Was it right to say "Welcome!" to her?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "Welcome".

Comment: For anyone walking in late, they get a slight nod and not a verbal greeting to embarrass them. Assume there's a good reason and don't advertise the moment.

Comment: It’s not clear to me what “incorporated stealthy and late into the shift” means.  Do you mean that they snuck in hoping no one would notice?? If that’s the case, your saying, “Welcome” is like saying “If you think you’re sneaking in unnoticed, you failed because I see you and I’m announcing it to everyone around me as well.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look of this article about *"What is the difference between greet and welcome?"*, you will see that *welcome* can also mean:

> Kind reception of a guest or newcomer. ([Wikidiff](https://wikidiff.com/greet/welcome))

[Askdifference](https://www.askdifference.com/greeting-vs-welcome/) says:

> A welcome is a kind of greeting designed ***to introduce a person to a new place or situation, and to make them feel at ease***.

So, in an environment where there is hierarchy, welcoming someone can be interpreted as a sign of superiority, even of condescending attitude. It is possible that your colleague implied that, being the boss, your supervisor is supposedly more entitled to ***welcome*** others to the area of which she is in charge. I don't know the context of your work, but your colleague probably felt you welcomed the host into their own home.

So it is better to be aware of the fact that, when you say ***"Welcome!"*** with your best intentions, some might interpret it (as your colleague seems to have done) as your assumption that you are the host, not the guest.

In a neutral context, I don't see why you shouldn't say "Welcome". If I had a conversation with my colleagues during a break at work and my boss appeared, I would say ***Welcome***.

Comment: So the meaning of "Welcome" depends on whether the place/supervisor imposes a weak or a strong hierarchy.

Comment: Hierarchy is a strong word. And it may be that your boss gives no thought to this. It may be your colleague's personal opinion that you should not 'welcome' someone in charge, someone who has worked for a longer time than you at that company. You can never know what is on people's minds and how they relate to superiors. I am just saying that when you say "welcome" with your best intentions, some might interpret it (as your colleague seems to have done) as your assumption that you are **the** host, not the guest.